# For loop only outputs last element

Tags: javascript, for-loop

Sorry if duplicate but cant seem to find the right answer anywhere:
In console.log the output is correct, but on the screen it only displays the last element of the array

```
    {id: 3, naam: "Besured", type: "Voor alle pakketten geldt:, Ready-2-go ,Love-2-move, Alles-in-1 ", vergoeding:"Registratie bij koepel vereist , Geen vergoeding, Geen vergoeding, 80% tot € 200 per jaar maximaal € 50 per consult"},

            var string = test[i].type;
            var thisString = string.split(",");


        for(var j=0; j<thisString.length;j++){
                console.log(thisString[j]);
                $('.first')[0].innerHTML = thisString[j];
                $('.second')[0].innerHTML = thisString[j];
                $('.third')[0].innerHTML = thisString[j];
                $('.fourth')[0].innerHTML = thisString[j];
            }
```

Comment: Well, obviously, that's what happens when you set something to a value and then immediately set it to a different value.

Comment: What would you *expect* this to do...?!

Comment: I want to display in the first class the first element of the array , second class the second element etc.

Comment: `$('.first')[0].innerHTML = thisString[0]; $('.second')[0].innerHTML = thisString[1]; ...` Look ma, no loop!

Comment: But not all are filled, and if it is empty I dont want to output it.

Comment: There are arrays with 3 elements, 4 elements, 7 elements etc. If they are empty I dont want to output anything. So thats why I want to use a for loop to see how many elements there are in the array and fill the amount of items there are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment says

> I need in the first element of the array in the first class, second
>   item in second class etc

then try

```
    $('.first').html( trimStr( thisString[0] ) ); 
    $('.second').html( trimStr( thisString[1] ) );
    $('.third').html( trimStr( thisString[2] ) );
    $('.fourth').html( trimStr( thisString[3] ) );

function trimStr( input ) {

    if (typeof input === 'undefined' || input == null) 
    {
        input =  "";
    }

    return input.trim();
}
```

Comment: If i do a += it displays ALL the items from the array in each class. I need in the first element of the array in the first class, second item in second class etc

Comment: But not all are filled, and if it is empty I dont want to output it.

Comment: @ElonGielink even it is empty, your element's innerHTML will stay empty. So no need to worry about empty elements

Comment: @Elon Well then, throw in an `if (thisString[0])` somewhere to check if you want to output it. Really, to get a more optimised approach to the whole thing which leads to elegant code, we'd need to know what exactly you're trying to do here to begin with.

Comment: It will say "undefined" if i do it like that because there is no element in the array if there are 3 elements and I call 7 elements (not all arrays are equal length, thats why I use the array.length)

Comment: @ElonGielink try the updated code with check for null or undefined

Comment: @gurvinder372 You're a legend mate. Thanks!

Comment: @ElonGielink is it? :)